# Javascript not trigering and alert function is working

Tags: javascript

I have Asp.net web application given by client with UI layer and its speaking with webservices. I am creating  another asp.net web application copy pasted all the HTML,CSS and images other files.

ERROR :

I have Master page and child page.

In child pages I have lot of JavaScript for validating the text box.

Javascript like:

$(document).ready

rules and messages)

they getting form tag from master for binding.

But when I click the submit button, it's not validation the control
and I have placed alert box inside the JavaScript and its working.

Kindly help here...

alert box  is working..and validation is not work in same JavaScript.

How to check the JavaScript is correctly bound with form tag?

Same problem appears in another set of master and Child page. I corrected the form tag. Like master page form tag should be in child page. It's validating properly.

Comment: put your javascript code here.

Comment: as long as you dont put the code you are having trouble with, we can only blind guess what went wrong.

Comment: Without your code no one can figure out whats happening. Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

alert outside the $(document).ready to check weather its coming inside the script also can you post the code for futhe

Comment: Ya <Script = Javascript >  {  alert  (HI)  $(document).ready and then mesages and rules... Same thing i copied from other web pages where its working there...I am sure ..there no problem in the validation logic..becasue i copied and changes the name accordingly.....Need to know  whether javascipr is binded or not with asp.net page.....Alert is workin....since it is a first step....